# Connection Error when connecting to DB2 LUW from DBeaver "com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException"

Tags: db2, dbeaver, db2-luw

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsKSB.png)

Error message under details button:
SqlException
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException

This is the error message received from the dbeaver logs

```
2023-11-16 19:13:38.091 - SqlException
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:815)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:66)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:140)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.completeSqlca(Connection.java:5269)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.q(z.java:861)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.n(z.java:670)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.a(z.java:474)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.a(z.java:123)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.c(b.java:1427)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:1298)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:849)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:820)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:441)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:414)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:352)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:233)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:200)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:471)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:113)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.lambda$0(JDBCDataSource.java:185)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.lambda$1(JDBCDataSource.java:204)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.utils.SecurityManagerUtils.wrapDriverActions(SecurityManagerUtils.java:94)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.openConnection(JDBCDataSource.java:202)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.db2.model.DB2DataSource.openConnection(DB2DataSource.java:273)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCExecutionContext.connect(JDBCExecutionContext.java:103)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCRemoteInstance.initializeMainContext(JDBCRemoteInstance.java:100)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCRemoteInstance.<init>(JDBCRemoteInstance.java:59)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.initializeRemoteInstance(JDBCDataSource.java:112)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.<init>(JDBCDataSource.java:100)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.<init>(JDBCDataSource.java:92)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.db2.model.DB2DataSource.<init>(DB2DataSource.java:128)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.db2.DB2DataSourceProvider.openDataSource(DB2DataSourceProvider.java:98)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.registry.DataSourceDescriptor.openDataSource(DataSourceDescriptor.java:981)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.registry.DataSourceDescriptor.connect(DataSourceDescriptor.java:918)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.jobs.ConnectJob.run(ConnectJob.java:70)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
2023-11-16 19:13:41.437 - Service 'org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.ui.UIServiceSecurity' not found
2023-11-16 19:14:00.845 - Service 'org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.ui.UIServiceSecurity' not found
```

I am getting sql exception error when I try to connect.

Things that I have already checked before posting this here

- Reinstalled Java SE
- Reinstalled Java JDK 21
- Installed IBM Data Server Driver Package (DS Driver)
- Reinstalled DBeaver
- Reinstalled DB2
- Checked my port number in services file

Comment: click the 'details' button on the sql-exception, and then copy/paste the full unedited exception detail into your question as plain text (not as an image).  Do not add a comment with new facts, because comments are not searchable.

Comment: it does not show anything else than 
  SqlException
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException. I have updated it in the question.

Comment: How did you verify that the Db2-server is started and also listening on port 25000 (normally 50000 is the default)? The Db2-registry variable DB2COMM value must include TCPIP and the Db2-server has to be restarted after setting this variable. The Microsoft Windows firewall needs to have inbound and outbound rules to allow traffic on the specified port(s) on which Db2-server is listening. This is all basic stuff, all explained in the online documentation pages.

Comment: I verified my port number is 25000 using C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\services. In this text file it shows this line at the very bottom: db2c_DB2 25000/tcp

Comment: The `services` file does _not_ determine what port Db2 uses; the instance configuration does, so check that.